# extracting residuals from pixel by pixel regression

Tags: r, raster, lm

I am trying to extract the residuals from a regression run pixel by pixel on a raster stack of NDVI/precipitation. My script works when i run it with a small part of my data. But when i try to run the whole of my study area i get: "Error in setValues(out, x) : values must be numeric, integer, logical or factor"

The lm works, since I can extract both slope and intercept. I just cant extract the residuals.

Any idea of how this could be fixed?

Here is my script:

```
setwd("F:/working folder/test")
gimms <- list.files(pattern="*ndvi.tif")
ndvi <- stack(gimms)
precip <- list.files(pattern="*pre.tif")
pre <- stack(precip)
s <- stack(ndvi,pre)

residualfun = function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ NA } else { m <- lm(x[1:6] ~ x[7:12], na.action=na.exclude)
r <- residuals.lm(m)
return (r)}}

res <- calc(s,residualfun)
```

And here is my data: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhwCgWqhyyDclJRjhh6GtentxFOKwQ

Comment: Hum, perhaps there's something wrong with your formula argument? I would call columns explicitly.

Comment: The link to your data is obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function only test if the first layer shows `NA` values to avoid fitting the model. But there may be `NA` in other layers. You know that because you added `na.action = na.exclude` in your `lm` fit.
The problem is that if the model removes some values because of `NA`, the residuals will only have the length of the non-NA values. This means that your resulting `r` vector will have different lengths depending on the amount of `NA` values in layers. Then, `calc` is not be able to combine results of different lengths in a stack a a defined number of layers.
To avoid that, you need to specify the length of `r` in your function and attribute residuals only to non-NA values.
I propose the following function that now works on the dataset your provided. I added (1) the possibility compare more layers of each if you want to extend your exploration (with `nlayers`), (2) avoid fitting the model if there are only two values to compare in each layer (perfect model), (3) added a `try` if for any reason the model can fit, this will output values of `-1e32` easily findable for further testing.

```
library(raster)
setwd("/mnt/Data/Stackoverflow/test")
gimms <- list.files(pattern="*ndvi.tif")
ndvi <- stack(gimms)
precip <- list.files(pattern="*pre.tif")
pre <- stack(precip)
s <- stack(ndvi,pre)

# Number of layers of each
nlayers <- 6

residualfun <- function(x) {
  r <- rep(NA, nlayers)
  obs <- x[1:nlayers]
  cov <- x[nlayers + 1:nlayers]
    # Remove NA values before model
    x.nona <- which(!is.na(obs) & !is.na(cov))
    # If more than 2 points proceed to lm
    if (length(x.nona) > 2) {
      m <- NA
      try(m <- lm(obs[x.nona] ~ cov[x.nona]))
      # If model worked, calculate residuals
      if (is(m)[1] == "lm") {
        r[x.nona] <- residuals.lm(m)
      } else {
        # alternate value to find where model did not work
        r[x.nona] <- -1e32
      }
    }
return(r)
}

res <- calc(s, residualfun)
```

[image: Residuals by layer]